# a-frame is saturating colors of my model texture

Tags: colors, model, textures, render, aframe

I been searching without luck this issue.

The rendering of a-frame is saturating the colors of my models.

I'm using the ambient and point light assigned by A-frame,
been testing on Mozilla.Hub and a frame . send you images of the renders in Firefox.

This is the render in mozilla.Hub , the colors I'm using are ok.
[image: this is the render in mozilla.Hub , the colors I'm using are ok]

and this is how A-frame is rendering them.
[image: and this is how A-frame is rendering them]

Answer (score 2):

Set [color management](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/renderer.html#colormanagement) to `true` in the [renderer component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/renderer.html).

```
<a-scene renderer="colorManagement: true"></a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried the colorManagment render but does not affect the glb model

I test with a box with a src image , and is rendering alright , but my glb model with same image is saturated
https://workable-root-workshop.glitch.me/

same glb model in hub, the colors are OK ,
i used blender to export
the same happen to the other models that don't use image as texture ,
saturated colors

Answer (score 0):

I was using and old version of aframe.min.js,
I change it, and render is OK now
I found about it in another post you make

Comment: Glad you found the solution. When asking questions share code that people can run. Tons of mistakes (like an outdated aframe version) will be caught quickly at a glance. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great!